# PHP - not sure how to ask - regarding variables and $_POST

Tags: php

I have a PHP form. The form works but I'm trying to test to see if a value other than the first item has been selected. I can't figure out how to write the If statement.

```
$products = array(
 '' => 1,
 'Item 2' => 2,
 'Item 3' => 3,
 'Item 4' => 4,
 'Item 5' => 5,
 'Item 6' => 6
);

$html = generateSelect('products', $products);

function generateSelect($name = '', $options = array()) {
 $html = '<select name="'.$name.'">';
 foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
  $html .= '<option value='.$value.'>'.$option.'</option>';
 }
 $html .= '</select>';
 return $html;
}
```

In my table, the drop down box is displayed:

```
<tr>
<td style="width:{$left_col_width}; text-align:left; vertical-align:center; padding:{$cell_padding}; font-weight:bold; {$product[3]}">{$product[0]}</td>
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:{$cell_padding};"><select name="{$product[1]}">
 <option value="1"></option>
 <option value="2">Item 2</option>
 <option value="3">Item 3</option>
 <option value="4">Item 4</option>
 <option value="5">Item 5</option>
 <option value="6">Item 6</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

I use the following if statement to check to see if someone has entered a phone number. if they have not entered a phone number, then the "Phone:" text turns red. How do I do an if statement similar to this to verify that someone has selected a product option from the drop down box?

```
  if(!empty($_POST['phone'])) {
   $phone[2] = clean_var($_POST['phone']);
   if (function_exists('htmlspecialchars')) $phone[2] = htmlspecialchars($phone[2], ENT_QUOTES);
  }
  else {
    $error = 1;
    $phone[3] = 'color:#d20128;';
  }
```

it seems simple but I can't figure it out.

EDIT 1:

I tried the suggestions, and the following works best so far:

```
if ($_POST['product'] != 1){
```

after I click the 'submit' button. the "Product:" text does turn red like expected; however, the drop down box resets to showing the option value 1 but the variable still remains at the selected value.

long questions short. how do I tell the dropdown box to show, for example, item 5?

Comment: In what situation would `htmlspecialchars` not be present?

Comment: in the case of a name, phone number, or address entry i suppose. such as in a input type="text" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, wouldn't this meet your needs?

```
if ($_POST['product'] != 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting the `value` of any "unselectable" or "un-filled-in" items to be `''` (i.e., the empty string). That way they'll look to PHP the same as a text input that didn't get filled in.

Your `!empty($_POST['phone'])` setup would then work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is make sure that that the value is not blank. When they select something, the value associated with that option is what is returned. **The better way** is to make sure that the value posted is within the allowed options (i.e. 1 <= x <= 6) because people *can* create false forms and post to your script with a value of, say, 7 (which is not blank).

So something like this:

```
if ($_POST[$product[1]] >= 1 && $_POST[$product[1]] <= 6) {
    // It's in range, do something
    // Make sure that $product[1] is defined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I tell the dropdown box to show, for example, item 5?

```
$products = array(
 '' => 1,
 'Item 2' => 2,
 'Item 3' => 3,
 'Item 4' => 4,
 'Item 5' => 5,
 'Item 6' => 6
);

    function generateSelect($name = '', $options = array()) {
     $html = '<select name="'.$name.'">';
     foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
      $html .= '<option value='.$value.'>'.$option.'</option>';
     }
     $html .= '</select>';
     return $html;
    }
```

For a start, your `$products array()` is an odd way around, I'd do it like this:

```
$products = array(
 '',
 'Item 2',
 'Item 3',
 'Item 4',
 'Item 5',
 'Item 6', // last comma optional, but I tend to put it in when I'm writing a vertical list
);
```

And then the `generateSelect()` function should take a value as well as the array.

```
function generateSelect($name='', $options=array(), $currValue='') {
 $html = '<select name="' . $name . '">';
 foreach ($options as $k => $v) {
  $html .= '<option value="' . $k . '"' . ($k == $currValue ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $v . '</option>';
 }
 $html .= '</select>';
 return $html;
}
```

Now if you a value has been selected, it will be kept, if you pass it to the `generateSelect()` function as `$currValue`. I think that was what you were asking.

Comment: i am trying your suggestion now but $currValue is not being set

Comment: how do I pass it to generateSelect()? and do i pass it when the user submits?

Comment: I don't have enough context of your code to tell you how to integrate these functions. As far as I understand it, you're displaying a form and then, on submit, you are displaying the form again with the submissions filled in. Yes? In that case, on submission, pass the received value (from the `$_POST` array, yes?) to the `generateSelect()`  function as `$currValue`.